# Glucagon Supplementation for weight loss

Tags: weight-loss, ketogenic-diet, atkins

I'm currently on the Dukan diet, so protein-only for the next week then protein and salad only.  The basis of Dukan, like atkins, is to push your body into a state of Ketosis where it starts to burn fat for energy rather than sugar.

This process can only begin when the Glycogen reserves in the liver have depleted.

Can I supplement with Glucagon to accelerate this process?  Are there any risks associated with this?

NB I am not diabetic.

Comment: Isn't Glucogon a prescription medication?

Comment: Yes but I wasn't on planning to get it through a doctor.

Comment: You should consult with your doctor for prescription drug advice. We cannot offer medical advice, as specified in the opening section of the [faq](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq).